# Facebook credits callback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to respond to Facebook requests while ordering an item like in the following sample (PHP): https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample/blob/master/callback.php

In my OrderProcess.aspx test page, Page_Load contains the following code:

```
var returnData = "{\"content\":[{\"title\":\"[Test Mode] Unicorn\",\"description\":\"[Test Mode] Own your own mythical beast!\",\"price\":2,\"image_url\":\"http://www.facebook.com//images//gifts//21.png\",\"product_url\":\"http://www.facebook.com//images//gifts//21.png\"}],\"method\":\"payments_get_items\"}";

    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; //tried most of them
    Response.Write(returnData);
```

But this does not work, Facebook returning the error "The application you are using is not responding correctly."

Can you help me with some sample code in C# duplicating the functionality in the above PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your content type to `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You should call Response.End().

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(returnData);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble finding any real substance for working with the horrible Facebook credits API documentation and converting it into asp.net, so I ended up writing a blog about how I finally got it working for my application. If you need the complete callback flow with examples, check out the post at

http://www.m-webs.com/blog_facebookcredits.html